# How to list users based on checkbox selection?

Tags: php

I have a text field and two checkboxes, I need to list users based on the selection. Can anyone show me an example.

Answer (score 1):

See:

[Enumerate all Check Box in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082152/enumerate-all-check-box-in-php)

```
<input name="rows[]" value="someVal" type="checkbox" />
<input name="rows[]" value="anotherVal" type="checkbox" />

<?php
    // $_POST['rows'] contains the values of all checked checkboxes

    //if something has been checked
    if(isset($_POST['rows'])) {

        //loop over each checked value
        foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) {
            echo $row . '<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to test isset($_POST['rows']) in case none are checked

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['mycheckbox']))
{
    draw_selectionCheckboxChecked();
}
else
{
    draw_NoCheckbox();
}
```